# How would you resolve this database design issue

Tags: sql, database-design

I am fairly new to databases and have been using books and tutorials to learn the Chen notation of databases.

I am working through an example whereby one of my Entity Diagrams has a situation whereby two strong entities connect to a weak entity.

This means the weak entity would have 2 foreign keys:  the primary key from both strong entities.

Here is a diagram of the design problem I am trying to resolve:
http://imgur.com/GXa0KSP

According to my newbie understanding this is incorrect, it will not work when creating db tables.

So my own solution is to create a base class i.e. "person" which connected to the "dependant" entity and "person is also the specialization class of student and teacher..

Is this the correct way to do it?

Or are there easier ways to resolve this?

Please kindly help

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it will not work? What happened when you tried?

Comment: "This means the weak entity would have 2 foreign keys: the primary key from both strong entities." It will show null for students  when searching for teachers and vice versa....not good practise IMO

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are attempting to define the FK's backwards.

This SQL works just fine

```
create table student (
     ID     int identity not null   primary key
    ,Name   varchar(20) not null    unique nonclustered
)

create table teacher(
     ID     int identity not null   primary key
    ,Name   varchar(20) not null    unique nonclustered
);

create table dependents(
     ID     int identity not null   primary key clustered
    ,StudentID int references student(ID)
    ,TeacherID int references teacher(ID)

    unique nonclustered (StudentID,TeacherID)
);

insert student(Name) values   ('Fred'),('George');
insert teacher(Name) values   ('Minerva'),('Severus');
insert dependents(StudentID,TeacherID)
select
    student.ID,teacher.ID
from (values
     ('Fred',  'Minerva')
    ,('George','Minerva')
    ,('Fred',  'Severus')
)d(StudentName,TeacherName)
join student on student.Name = d.StudentName
join teacher on teacher.Name = d.TeacherName;

select
     StudentName = student.Name
    ,TeacherName = teacher.Name
from dependents
join student on student.ID = dependents.StudentID
join teacher on teacher.ID = dependents.teacherID

drop table dependents;
drop table teacher;
drop table student;
```

to yield as desired:

```
StudentName          TeacherName
-------------------- --------------------
Fred                 Minerva
Fred                 Severus
George               Minerva
```

Comment: thanks but how do I see the dependants of Student: George  or how do I see the dependants of Minerva? I am more interested in the dependants not which teacher is associated to which student and vice versa...

Comment: @xirokx: Add a where clause and additional columns to the final SELECT statement. Even define it as a VIEW if convenient.

Comment: Will I not receive NULL fields ? for example, if I choose to view a Students dependants the teachers dependants will be NULL and vice versa...have you tried it?